# How to scrape HTML from a javascript webpage using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, linux, screen-scraping

Trying to parse the html in order to get data from  tags nested inside of  tags, but when I prettify I get javascript. How do I get the information out of this javascript? How do I turn it into html? Is there a better way to get this information? This is my first question and I apologize if I've made any mistakes. Thank you.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

html = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(html.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

The response is:
what looks like byte/string of pre-prettified code followed by

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script language="javascript">
var strUrl = window.location.href;


if (strUrl.indexOf("modisoftinc.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoftinc.com/home.html");
if (strUrl.indexOf("www.modisoftinc.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoftinc.com/home.html");
if (strUrl.indexOf("http://modisoftinc.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoftinc.com/home.html");
if (strUrl.indexOf("www.modisoftinc.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoftinc.com/home.html");


if (strUrl.indexOf("echecks.modisoftinc.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://echecks.modisoftinc.com/Account/Logon");


if (strUrl.indexOf("pos.modisoftinc.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://pos.modisoftinc.com/Account/Logon");


if (strUrl.indexOf("clock.modisoftinc.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://clock.modisoftinc.com/Account/Logon");


if (strUrl.indexOf("admin11.modisoftinc.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://admin11.modisoftinc.com/Account/Logon");




if (strUrl.indexOf("modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoft.com/home.html");
if (strUrl.indexOf("www.modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoft.com/home.html");
if (strUrl.indexOf("http://modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoft.com/home.html");
if (strUrl.indexOf("www.modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoft.com/home.html");


if (strUrl.indexOf("echecks.modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://echecks.modisoft.com/Account/Logon");

if (strUrl.indexOf("app.modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://app.modisoft.com/Account/Logon");

if (strUrl.indexOf("app1.modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://app1.modisoft.com/Account/Logon");

if (strUrl.indexOf("app2.modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://app2.modisoft.com/Account/Logon");

if (strUrl.indexOf("pos.modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://pos.modisoft.com/Account/Logon");

if (strUrl.indexOf("clock.modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://clock.modisoft.com/Account/Logon");

    if (strUrl.indexOf("admin11.modisoft.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://admin11.modisoft.com/Account/Logon");



if (strUrl.indexOf("modisoftrewards.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoftrewards.com/index.html");
if (strUrl.indexOf("www.modisoftrewards.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoftrewards.com/index.html");
if (strUrl.indexOf("http://modisoftrewards.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoftrewards.com/index.html");
if (strUrl.indexOf("www.modisoftrewards.com") > 0)
    window.location.replace("https://www.modisoftrewards.com/index.html");






   if (strUrl.indexOf("localhost") > 0)
       window.location.replace("Account/Logon");
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't turn it into html. Depending on what you want from the page you will need to automate a browser to let javascript run on the page and then grab what you want, or use the network tab/network monitoring tool to see if the content you want is available from another uri by xhr and make a request to that endpoint

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the information out of this javascript? How do I turn it into html?

Yes, you need a browser automation (selenium, headless Chrome) to execute on-site JS. Then upon that, the JS fills in HTML with missing data.
Eg.:

1. https://webscraping.pro/javascript-rendering-library-for-scraping-javascript-sites/
2. https://webscraping.pro/java-library-to-scrape-linkedin-its-data-affiliates/

### Hack

In some cases you might use `a bare coding` (python, php) to **imitate JS requests** (usually XHR/Ajax) and get the missing info. Eg. [Scrape a JS Lazy load page by Python requests](https://webscraping.pro/scrape-lazy-load-page-python-requests/)